# Fedora 24 Boots to read only

Tags: fedora, storage

Ok so I have been researching this problem all day but I have a clean install of fedora 24 server and after installing some virtualization packages and rebooting from the console it boots up with the root file system in read only (ro). I can't execute or write anything until after I remount the system (mount -o remount /). This has occurred across multiple re installs of fedora.

the root filesystem is a XFS on a lvm partition on my SSD (the physical drive is /dev/sdc). I have tried using XFS_repair and it tells me something is wrong with my first superblock but I get a "can't find 2nd superblock" error. I have searched for bad blocks in my SSD but nothing was turned up. The Smart Status of my drive is PASSED. I searched [this Dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/mVJRtcXN) and can't seem to find anything relate-able to I/O or my storage drives.

I don't know enough about fedora so I don't know where to look or what to look for on google. I'll take any help I can get: a fish, a fishing pole or a lake; doesn't matter to me.

If it helps I am using a xeon e5-2670 on an intel x79 motherboard with 16 GB RAM, 120gg kingston ssd, 2x 3TB WD RED NAS drives in RAID 1, a HD5750 and a mellanox 10GBe NIC

Answer (score 0):

DMSG should tell you if your fstab has issue.  It look like your system is booting incorrectly.  You need check your system grub.conf file and make sure it boot into right image.

Comment: This grub.conf file is found /etc/default/grub right?

Comment: /etc/grub.conf is a soft link  to /boot/grub/grub.conf